# Computing $\int_B e^{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac32}} \ dx \ dy \ dz$, where $B$ denotes is the unit sphere.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Compute the integral $$\int_B e^{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac32}} \ dx \ dy \ dz$$ where $B= \{(x,y,z) \mid x^2+y^2+z^2 \leqslant 1 \}.$

My approach was to do a spherical coordinate transform and proceed from there, but had trouble finding the limits of integration...

After the transformation I'm left with $$\int_B e^{{r^2}^{\frac32}} r^2\sin(\varphi) \ dr \ d\varphi \ d\theta$$

Since I'm dealing with the unit sphere and I have that $r \in [0,1]$ I considered $\theta\in[0, 2\pi]$ and $\varphi \in [0, \pi]$ which would cover the whole sphere and thus

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{1} e^{{r^2}^{\frac32}} r^2\sin(\varphi) \ dr \ d\varphi \ d\theta$$

which will evaluate to $4\pi \cdot \frac{e-1}{3}$. I'm not sure that I got the limits right though...

Shouldn't I only consider the positive quadrant, since the integrand isn't never negative?

Comment: Yes that is correct. It is basically $e^{r^3} \ r^2 \ sin \phi$.

Comment: Correct that I should only consider the positive quadrant? @MathLover

Comment: No your region is the whole sphere so integral is correct. I was just saying you could simplify and write it as $e^{r^3}$.

Comment: and your final answer is correct as well.

Comment: On your specific confusion on whether you should integrate over specific quadrants only, the integrand does not decide the limits. It is the region you are integrating over decides the limits. For example, if the region was given as $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1, z \geq 0 $ then your limits for $\phi$ will be $0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. I hope it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there: $\int_0^1 r^2e^{r^3}dr=[\tfrac13e^{r^3}]_0^1=\tfrac13(e-1)$ is the hard part.